# A set of $n$ orthonormal vectors provides a basis for $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

Let $\{v_1,...,v_n\} \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ be a set of mutually orthogonal, non-zero vectors of length $1$.

How does one prove that this set is a basis of $\mathbb R^n$?

I have already proved that they are linearly independent, but I still need to prove that they span $\mathbb R^n$. I have also read that a set of $n$ linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb R^n$   is a basis, but I couldn't find a proof of this theorem.

Comment: Prove that $\forall x \in \Bbb R^n: x = (x \cdot v_1) v_1 + \cdots + (x \cdot v_n) v_n$

Comment: Any linearly independent set with cardinality $n$ forms a basis for  $\mathbb{R}^n$. Even it is true for any $n$ dimensional vector space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume they don't span $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then you can keep adding vectors $u_1,..u_k$ so that at each step, $v_1,...,v_n, u_1,...,u_k$ is free. Since $\mathbb{R}^n$ is finite dimensional, this process stops eventually, so that $v_1,...,v_n,u_1,...u_k$ is free and spans $\mathbb{R}^n$, so it's a basis

But a well-known theorem asserts that any two bases of a (finite dimensional - or with the axiom of choice, any) vector space have the same cardinality, so that $n+k = n$, $k=0$ : $v_1,...,v_n$ spans $\mathbb{R}^n$.

For a more detailed proof you can look up the incomplete basis theorem, which asserts that in a finite dimensional vector space, any free family can be expanded to a basis (actually this is true of any vector space if you add the axiom of choice)

Comment: What does "free" mean?

Comment: Linearly independent, sorry it's a mistranslation of the word in my language.

Comment: How can one prove the incomplete basis theorem?

Comment: I forgot the proof my teacher gave (that was specific for finite dimensional vector spaces, but didn't need any choice) but I found another one involving Zorn's lemma (which is valid regardless of the dimension). Is that ok with you ?

Comment: Nevermind, I re-found it ! Let $(f_i)_{i\in I}$ be a finite generating family for $V$ (where $V$ is the vector space in question- it exists by definition). Let $(v_1,...,v_n)$ be linearly independent vectors in $V$. Then consider the process I was describing : add vectors of $(f_i)$ in the family one at a time, making sure at each step that the resulting family is still linearly independant. If you can't add $f_i$, then it means that $f_i$ is in the span of the family at the earlier step so that's not a problem. Since $I$ is finite, this process terminates.

Comment: Once it terminates, each vector $f_i$ is either in the family, or is in its span. Thus the family we built is linearly independent by construction, and it spans $(f_i)$, thus since it's a generating family, it spans $V$. So there is a linearly independent family containing $v_1,...,v_n$ and spanning $V$

Comment: A "generating family" means the same as "a family that spans", yes?

Comment: Yes sorry, it must be a mistranslation again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this would count as extremely rigorous, but I was just working on this question today, and this is how I would answer it.

We have the set of vectors which are orthogonal and of unit length. Therefore, they form some sort of basis for the space (since the vectors are linearly independent). We then note that this basis is given by the span of $(v_1,...,v_n)$, which means the dimension of this space is the number of vector elements that we used. The number of vectors is $n$, so the dimension is $n$. This is the same dimension as $\mathbb R^n$. Since the dimension of $\mathbb R^n$ is $n$, we know that any linearly independent set of $n$ vectors will span this space, which means our set is a basis for $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: I might say instead at the end that the vectors span all of $\mathbb R^n$ because that’s its only $n$-dimensional subspace, or just fall back on the definition of dimension.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you. I did indeed fall back onto the definition of dimension, which is the number of vectors in the basis (which we found in this example to be $n$). Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: “... since the two spaces have the same dimension” doesn’t directly justify the conclusion. The key fact is that *any* set of $n$ linearly independent vectors spans the entire space.

Comment: Alright, I think I understand what you mean. I'll edit the post.

Answer (score 0):

Any linearly independent set with cardinality $n$ forms a basis for  $\mathbb{R}^n$. Even it is true for any $n$ dimensional vector space.