# Showing a set of vectors form an orthonormal basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, orthogonality

[How to quickly check if vectors are an orthonormal basis of a vector space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2194772/how-to-quickly-check-if-vectors-are-an-orthonormal-basis-of-a-vector-space/2194790)

According to the above link,  we can check if a set of vectors  are an **orthonormal basis** of some vector space $V$ by checking if the vectors in the set are:

- all orthogonal to each other: "ortho"
- all of unit length: "normal"
- (if the set of vectors are orthonormal, then the set of vectors are linearly independent)

But doesn't this just show that we have an orthonormal set of vectors?

How do we know the set of vectors are an orthonormal basis of some vector space $V$? In other words how do we know the set of vectors span the vector space $V$?

Comment: The question asks for "some vector space" so it could be a subspace of the original space.  Vectors always span their span.  If you want a specific vector space, then, yes, you need to check that they are spanning.

Comment: @MichaelBuff can you elaborate on "vectors always span their span"

Comment: There is a difference between the questions "are the vectors $\{v_1,\dots,v_k\}$ a basis for $V$" and "are the vectors $\{v_1,\dots,v_k\}$ a basis for a vector space".  The first specifies the vector space $V$, while the second allows you to pick the appropriate vector space.  In the second formulation, you can use the vector space $W=\operatorname{Span}(v_1,\dots,v_k)$.  In this case, $\{v_1,\dots,v_k\}$ already span $W$, all you need to do is to check that they're independent to be a basis for $W$.  If you require the vectors to be a basis for $V$, then you must check that they span $V$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set of vectors should also span the whole space.

If we know the dimension of the space then we should simply count the orthonormal vectors and make sure that we have as many vectors in our basis as the dimension of the space.

Otherwise, we have to prove that every vector is a linear combination of the basis vectors.

Comment: so for example given a vector set ${u_1,u_2,u_3}$, we can first show that it is an orthonormal set, then we can show it is an orthonormal basis for $R^3$ just by counting the orthonormal vectors and making sure that we have as many vectors in the basis as the dimension of the space (which it does) but what if we have something like $u_1=(1,0,0)^T$, $u_2=(2,0,0)^T$, $u_3=(3,0,0)^T$

Comment: Yes, if you know the dimension, we just count them.

Comment: but if $u_1=(1,0,0)^T$, $u_2=(2,0,0)^T$, $u_3=(3,0,0)^T$, then there is no way it can span $R^3$

Comment: They are not orthonormal.

Comment: is there a theorem that states what you explained?

Comment: answering myself: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2230915/a-set-of-n-orthonormal-vectors-provides-a-basis-for-mathbb-rn

ty Dr.Riazi-Kermani

Comment: Yes, the theorem states that orthogonal vectors are linearly independent. Dimension of the space is the minimum number of linearly independent vectors  which spans the space.